# Scale ImageView to parents height while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin

After a long search and only finding results for scaling the width of an ImageView I hope someone can help me with my problem.

I have two LinearLayouts under each other and fill them at runtime with 24 ImageViews (12 per LinearLayout). Both Layouts take the same amount of height-space and now I want to scale the ImageViews so that they take the same height as the LinearLayout that contains them while keeping the aspect ratio of the image inside the ImageView.

I tried till know many different things like setScaleType, setAdjustViewBounds or writing my own ImageView class with overriding onMeasure, but nothing worked so far that the ImageView took the whole height available from its parent layout.

Maybe I didn't combined the right thinks together so I hope someone can help me with this issue.

EDIT:

The size of the source Image is always 92 x 128.

Layout:

firstCardHolder and secondCardHolder are the layouts holding the ImageViews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:orientation="vertical"
p1:minWidth="25px"
p1:minHeight="25px"
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="match_parent"
p1:id="@+id/contentHolder">
<LinearLayout
    p1:orientation="horizontal"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:id="@+id/timerLayout"
    p1:gravity="center"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    p1:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    <TextView
        p1:text="03:00"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        p1:textSize="26dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<HorizontalScrollView
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:id="@+id/wordListScroll"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_below="@+id/timerLayout"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="horizontal"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/wordScrollLayout"
        p1:gravity="center_vertical" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    p1:orientation="horizontal"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/footerLayout"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    p1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    p1:clipChildren="false"
    p1:clipToPadding="false">
    <TextView
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/hiraganaCombo"
        p1:gravity="center"
        p1:textSize="32dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<HorizontalScrollView
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
    p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:layout_below="@+id/wordListScroll"
    p1:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    p1:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        p1:orientation="vertical"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollContentLayout">
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="horizontal"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:layout_weight="0.5"
            p1:id="@+id/firstCardHolder"
            p1:background="#ff009411"
            p1:minWidth="25px"
            p1:minHeight="25px" />
        <LinearLayout
            p1:orientation="horizontal"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:layout_weight="0.5"
            p1:id="@+id/secondCardHolder"
            p1:background="#ffd20000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with getting the height of the parent layout at runtime and calculating with it the width of my ImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

[Try ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_INSIDE.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

"Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding)."

Hope that helps!

Comment: I just confirmed it again (tried that already). On my test device its almost fitting, but under each row of ImageViews is still  some space left. On the emulator with different settings than on the device the ImageViews are very small, so not really scaling to the height they could take.

Comment: Please add your layout code for the enclosing views. There must be something wrong there.

Comment: Added Layout to question!

Comment: Still doesn't show the parented height. Please show me what you have programmed for the height of these layouts.

Comment: I edited now all of the layout xml code in, but maybe I'm just misunderstanding you. I didn't coded anything into the actual program code for these LinearLayouts. For the ImageViews, I'm only creating at runtime a new ImageView object and passing it a drawable as source.